# ¿Cómo unir dos arrays a partir de otro en php?

Tags: sql, sql-server, php8, sqlsrv

Tengo dos consultas a una base de datos sql server en la primera consulta selecciono la id de los usuarios y en la segunda consulta deberia seleccionar los nombres de los usuarios según el valor que me devuelve el primer array, la primera consulta funciona pero la segunda no obtiene todos los datos de los usuarios solo devuelve el último valor de la tabla **users** que está asociada a la tabla ***COLABORADOR***, el segundo array deberia obtener todos los nombres que están en la tabla **COLABORADOR**, las dos consultas se imprimen en un resultado final uniendolos en un solo array, !alguien podria ayudarme por favor les agradeceria¡

```html
<?php

$serverName = "server";
$connectionInfo = array("Database" => "mybd", "UID" => "SA", "PWD" => "1234", "CharacterSet" => "UTF-8");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);

///SELECCIONA LOS NOMBRES DEL USUARIO
$sql = "select iduser as otherInfo  FROM users";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

$datos = [];
//for ($i = 0; $i < count($datos2); $i++) {
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $datos[] = $row;
  $nombre_busqueda = strtoupper(strtolower(utf8_encode($row['otherInfo'])));
}

if (isset($row)) {
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    $json = json_encode(array('code' => 200, 'status' => 'ok', 'message' => 'Success SELECT', 'data' => $datos), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);


///SELECCIONA LOS CODIGOS DEL USUARIO SEGUN EL NOMBRE FILTRADO EN EL ARRAY
$sql1 = "select cod_user as COD_FUNC FROM COLABORADOR where iduser= '$nombre_busqueda'";
$stmt1 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql1);

$datos1 = [];
while ($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $datos1[] = $row1;
    $nombre_busqueda = strtoupper(strtolower(utf8_encode($row1['otherInfo'])));
}

if (isset($row1)) {
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    $json1 = json_encode(array('code' => 200, 'status' => 'ok', 'message' => 'Success SELECT', 'data' => $datos1), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
}
sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt1);


$resultado = array_merge($datos,$datos1);
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Comment: En el primer `while`, esta variable `$nombre_busqueda = strtoupper( ... )` se está sobreescribiendo por cada iteración, así que solo tendrá el último valor de esa iteración. Cuando se lo aplicas a la segunda consulta solo buscará datos de ese usuario.

Answer (score 1):

según entiendo tu problema se da porque en ningún momento esta ejecutando un ciclo que recorra tu ARREGLO **$datos**, por ende, te da el ultimo valor del recorrido del while, no puedes utilizar la variable **$nombre_busqueda** ya que los datos los pasas como una cadena, debería ser un array para después recorrerlo, por eso tome tu variable **$datos** que guarda los datos del while de tu primer consulta como arreglo.

Esta seria la parte de tu segunda consulta.

```js
//SELECCIONA LOS CODIGOS DEL USUARIO SEGUN EL NOMBRE FILTRADO EN EL ARRAY
if(count($datos)>0){//VALIDA QUE EL ARREGLO DE LA PRIMER CONSULTA TENGA DATOS
  foreach($datos as $usuario => $id){//RECORRE ARREGLO DE LA PRIMERA CONSULTA Y EJECUTA LA SEGUNDA CONSULTA SEGÚN EL TAMAÑO DEL ARREGLO
    $sql2 = "select cod_user as COD_FUNC FROM COLABORADOR where iduser= '$id'";
    $stmt2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql1);
  }
  $datos2 = [];
  while ($row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt1, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      $datos2[] = $row2;
      $nombre_busqueda2 = strtoupper(strtolower(utf8_encode($row1['otherInfo'])));
  }

  if (isset($row2)) {
      header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
      $json1 = json_encode(array('code' => 200, 'status' => 'ok', 'message' => 'Success SELECT', 'data' => $datos1), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
  }
  sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt2);
}

$resultado = array_merge($datos,$datos2);
echo json_encode($resultado);
```

Esta practica no es recomendable, ya que se satura la carga de respuesta de la BD. No comprendo la forma en que quieres mostrar los datos, ya que podrías hacer la petición completa de **ids** con **nombre de usuario** directamente en una consulta cruzada a la BD.

**NOTA:** Si ya tienes una variable ejemplo: **$row** por secuencia al declarar otra similar seria **$row2** no **$row1**, o ponle un nombre con la que identifiques que tipo de dato contiene, facilita la lectura de tu código posteriormente.